# VIM search and replace

Tags: regular-expression, vim

I am trying to use a regex to search/replace a pattern / substitution / in vim.

I have a Java file which is trying to check if a weather data variable is set and if it is do one thing, if not omit it from being processed into JSON format. I wrote a method in a different class ( called StumpJunk.isSet - works just like PHP isset by checking if null or empty)

The old way I was doing it was 
    if (varName != null)

The new pattern I want it to be is 
    if (StumpJunk.isset(varName))

I have tried multiple regex methods in VIM to no luck:

```
:%s/if (\(.*\)) != null)/(StumpJunk.isSet(\1))/g
:%s/if \(\(.*\)\) \!\= null\)/\(StumpJunk.isSet\(\1\)\)/g
:%s/if \v\((.*)\) \!\= null\)/(StumpJunk.isSet(\1))/g
:%s/if \v\((.*)\) \!\= null\)/(StumpJunk.isSet("\1")/g
```

Every time it comes back saying pattern not found:

```
Pattern not found: \vif\((.*) \!\= null\)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `)` too many in the first pattern, and you lack `if` in the replacement:

```
:%s/if (\(.*\) != null)/if (StumpJunk.isSet(\1))/g
```

Comment: or `:%s/\vif \((.*) \!\= null\)/if (StumpJunk.isSet(\1))/g` if you want to use very-magic regex mode.